# Xamarin.Forms app not apply code changes from second project assembly without clean/rebuild solution

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, .net-assembly, solution, rebuild

I use the `VS Professional 2019 Version 16.7.7` and the latest `Xamarin.Forms`. Working only with `Android` part on `Windows 10`.
I have the simple blank app with one `MainPage` and `MainViewModel`, where the viewmodels' part is implemented as separate assembly. In the `ctor` of viewmodel I initialize test string, which show on UI via Binding.

And the issue in the next: when I start application at first time - everything is OK, but when I change some code in the ViewModels assembly (for example - change test string value) and relaunch nothing happen. Application apply these changes only after clean/rebuild the whole solution. At the breakpoint we can see the old property value.
[image: first normal start]
[image: relaunch without new changes]

I've uploaded the sample to the [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1507isz5lX_U6204y5o0_maq7ehBeHKFq), if someone want to try to reproduce issue

Comment: That's because of you put the ViewModel in a separate project . You could move them to the share project and the issue will been solved .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Do you know about some official restricted from Microsoft and Xamarin?
The best architecture and mvvm practices says that we need separate layer with business logic from UI layer.

Comment: Yes , that means we would better separate code of logic handling from UI . We need to create separate ViewaModel file (not a separate project)  .You could check project structure from this official sample https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/UserInterface/Xaminals/Xaminals

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Thanks for the information and the link. But on the VS 2019 ver. 16.5.4 everything is builds and works okey (i sent this solution to colleagues). Also i worked on a few big production Xamarin Forms projects with separated assemblies architecture early((

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT I think have VM as separate project isn't a real problem. actually I've already had the same issue. I can suggest clear the VS' cache.